# How to detect url from plain text from mysql table and echo in table row

Tags: php, mysql

[image]Hello Everyone,

I"m retrieving values from column called 'comment' of mysql table by echo. But This column has both plain text and some url also. When displaying value, I"m looking forward to identify the link from text and make it clickable.

Here is my code

```
 $postid= $_GET['post_id'];
          $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from tblcomment as c join tbluser as u on c.user_Id=u.user_Id where post_Id='$postid' order by datetime");
          $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
          if($num>0){
          while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

                 echo "<p class='well'>".$row['comment']."</p>";
          }

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider parse_url()? Returns false if it is unable to parse the string argument as an URL. You might want to try it on your non URL strings to be sure that it works in your case, though.

Comment: `post_Id='$postid'` looks to be prone to SQL injections.

Comment: Umm I will need help with this also later but I'm bound by this problem if any rows has comment from user...then before display detect url if there is any and make it as link and others as plain test and display it.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo I searched for your suggested method..but i couldn't get idea how that will solve my problem of diplaying links as clickable url and others as plain text from column value.

Comment: @redface "If parse_url() is able to parse the string, then assume it's an URL. Otherwise treat it as plain text." ..-ish.

..or are you looking for the HTML anchor element?

Comment: @redface Ok, probably my bad here. I thought the comment would be either text or an URL. But you want the comment to support a mix, right? Then I'd say regexp is the only way.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo yes that is correct..I think I might find a way..but I'm testing this one..but still any solution is very much welcome.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo Solved it...finally..and anyway Thanks for support and help.

Comment: @redface How about adding your answer here :)?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo Umm I edited my question including solution too.